# datastax cassandra java driver PlainTextAuthProvider example

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I got an exception for the code below, caused by

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected class com.datastax.driver.core.PlainTextAuthProvider (specified by advanced.auth-provider.class) to be a subtype of com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.auth.AuthProvider

```
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.config.DefaultDriverOption;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.config.DriverConfigLoader;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.config.ProgrammaticDriverConfigLoaderBuilder;
import org.asynchttpclient.netty.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.policies.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy;
import com.datastax.driver.core.PlainTextAuthProvider;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Metadata;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Host;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import com.datastax.driver.core.JdkSSLOptions;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.metadata.DefaultEndPoint;

    private void test_cqlsession(String trustStoreLocation, String password, List<String> ips) {

        ProgrammaticDriverConfigLoaderBuilder configBuilder = DriverConfigLoader
                .programmaticBuilder()
                .withClass(DefaultDriverOption.AUTH_PROVIDER_CLASS, PlainTextAuthProvider.class)
                .withString(DefaultDriverOption.AUTH_PROVIDER_USER_NAME, USER_NAME)
                .withString(DefaultDriverOption.AUTH_PROVIDER_PASSWORD, password)
                .withInt(DefaultDriverOption.CONNECTION_MAX_REQUESTS, 32768);

        if (trustStoreLocation != null) {
            configBuilder
                    .withClass(DefaultDriverOption.SSL_ENGINE_FACTORY_CLASS, DefaultSslEngineFactory.class)
                    .withString(DefaultDriverOption.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PATH, trustStoreLocation)
                    .withString(DefaultDriverOption.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD, password);
        }

        CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder()
                .withConfigLoader(configBuilder.build())
                .addContactEndPoints(
                        Arrays.stream(ips.toArray())
                        .map(host -> new DefaultEndPoint(
                                InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved(host.toString(), 9042)))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                )
                .withLocalDatacenter(DATA_CENTER)
                .build();

    .
    .
    .

}
```

I didn't find an example of how this should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a project that uses 2 versions of the Java driver: 3.x & 4.x. You need to remove dependency on the driver 3.x, where `PlainTextAuthProvider` is defined.

Also, instead of:

```
.withClass(DefaultDriverOption.AUTH_PROVIDER_CLASS, PlainTextAuthProvider.class)
                .withString(DefaultDriverOption.AUTH_PROVIDER_USER_NAME, USER_NAME)
                .withString(DefaultDriverOption.AUTH_PROVIDER_PASSWORD, password)
```

in configuration, just use:

```
CqlSession session =
    CqlSession.builder()
        .withAuthCredentials("user", "pass")
```

as described in [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.2/manual/core/authentication/#programmatically).